# inbound property mule create

Tags: java, mule

Why does this code allow someone to create an inbound message property in a Message Processor (like a Java component)

```
message.setProperty("myProperty", PropertyScope.INBOUND" );
```

but this does not

```
<set-property value="100" propertyName="myProperty" />
```

Per documentation, only message source should be able to create inbound property, then why is a Java component able to set inbound message property?

Comment: for someone reason, it does not show this part 
`<set-property value="100" propertyName="property" doc:name="Property" />`

Comment: Fixed your question. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thanks David, i see the formatting tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - that does violate the documented behavior of inbound properties.  As further, proof if you try to set an inbound property using the expression component:

```
<expression-component>
  message.inboundProperties['foo'] = 'bar'
</exporession-component>
```

At runtime will throw the following error:

```
Exception stack is:
1. The inbound message property "foo" cannot be added, updated or removed 
   because inbound message properties are immutable (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)
  org.mule.el.context.MessagePropertyMapContext:47 (null)
```

However Javadoc for [setProperty](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope%29) says:

> Set a property on the message. End-users should prefer more
>   scope-specific methods for readability. This one is more intended for
>   programmatic scope manipulation and Mule internal use.

So the takeaway is that setProperty is for internal Mule use, you should use setInvocationProperty, setOutboundProperty or setSessionProperty.  That is interesting to know because I'm sure I have used setProperty before.

Comment: I am not sure still, for instance how then do you explain this?  [http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Message+Structure]
Properties have two main scopes: inbound and outbound. 

Inbound properties are immutable, are automatically generated by the message source and cannot be set or manipulated by the user.  They contain metadata specific to the message source that prevents scrambling of data formats or other processing mishaps later in the message's lifecycle. A message retains its inbound properties only for the duration of the flow

Comment: I hadn't actually tried the example I gave you.  After trying it, I see that Mule will actually throw an error if you try to set an inbound property through an expression.  I updated my answer based on this new information.